# How to make pip install accept server's public key?

Tags: ssh, pip

I have a private git repo and need to configure my deployment scripts to pip install all the requirements, including an app from the private repo. I have my ssh agent configured for forwarding, so the authentication of myself is not a problem - the problem is that a fresh development machine does not have the repo's server public key in `.ssh/known_hosts`, so pip install fails with:

> Host key verification failed.

Is there any way to make `pip install` silently accept the public key and do not complain? I'm aware about the security implications, this is just for testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

either

1) find the host key .ssh/known_hosts and add it to `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` as part of your server setup

or

2) add the option

```
StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

to .ssh/config or the /etc/ssh/config

Option 1) is "better" as it is more secure

Comment: Thanks for the hints, but it's not really what I was looking for. The former is better for security, but not suitable for me right now. The latter turns it off for everything, I'd like to turn it off just temporarily, just for that one pip install call.

Comment: ``mv .ssh/config .ssh/config.real; echo "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" > .ssh/config; pip install git+ssh://://git@github.com/whatever/repo; mv .ssh/config.real .ssh/config``

Comment: Alright, I think I should have put more emphasis on the actual question, rather than explaining the (example) background :-) What I'm looking for is how to *make pip install accept the certificate* - that's it. I was hoping for some clean way to do it, with no side-effects...

Comment: I think the way I look at it is that pip uses ssh as a black box, the ``Host key verification failed.`` is from ssh and the way to fix it is to fix it at the ssh layer.  If ssh can ignore or accept the host key then pip will.  Maybe someone with better pip voodoo than me could suggest a way to pass an ssh option into pip

Comment: From what I see it really looks like there's no way to set this on pip level. I know pip uses ssh in the background, but it could be able to control some key options according to user's wishes... Well, never mind, I'll accept your answer if nobody else finds the ultimate solution :-)

Comment: If you are going with the ssh config option, I suggest making the setting limited the the github host. `printf "Host github.com\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> ~/.ssh/config` NOTE that `echo -e` is not POSIX standard and should be avoided. That's why I use printf if I need anything more than a basic echo.

Answer (score 7):

Late to the party, but this should work with git+ssh urls:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' pip install -r requirements.txt
```